# Custom View onDraw method

Tags: android, view

I want to make a custom View so I extended the View class and override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method.

The problems is, I found out that the method is never stopped being called.

well it seems that calling `View.invalidate` on a different View causes this view to redraw to.

I can't post the code in here so I try to describe only the relevant parts.

in the activity I create a `FrameLayout m_mainLayout` which is the one I finally pass to `setContentView()` method.

I add different Views and Layouts to m_mainLayout, one of them is `GameView m_gameView` which extends `View` and a `GameFrameView` which extends `RelativeLayout` and to this layout I add the View in question.

now, I constantly call (every ~100 ms) `m_gameView.invalidate()`.

how does it cause other views to be redrawn ?

what do I need to do to stop this?

Comment: Post your code please. I am almost sure that reason is different from what you're describing.

Comment: do you have a `super.onDraw`?

Comment: no, i don't called `super.onDraw`. I posted the code

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas); <-- add this
    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();
    Log.i("AttackDialogView", "onDraw "); 
}
```

Comment: I cannot post the whole code but I try to add only the related part